# Cannot delete row in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I get an error on delete a row in a SQLite database.
May be I did a mistake on constraint. Need some help.

My first table contains numbers which can be used in other table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE message_numbers (
    number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC
);

INSERT INTO message_numbers (number) VALUES (1), (10), (100);
```

The 2nd table has a constraint to use only numbers from the 1st table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE messages_ger (
    number  INTEGER NOT NULL
                    UNIQUE,
    message TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        number
    )
    REFERENCES message_numbers (number) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

INSERT INTO messages_ger (number, message) VALUES (100, 'Test');
```

If I try to delete a row from a table I get an error:

```sql
DELETE FROM messages_ger WHERE number=100;
```

***[09:46:09] Error while executing SQL query on database 'myDB': no such column: new.number***

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **What I'm doing wrong?**

It apears that you have a **TRIGGER** defined, *at a guess an **ON DELETE** Trigger*, and a statment in the **BEGIN** ... **END** clause or the **WHEN** clause is trying to reference **new.number** when **new** can only be used in **ON INSERT** or **ON UPDATE** triggers. as per :-

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of
> the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the
> form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the
> name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.
> OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
> which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> - INSERT  NEW references are valid
> - UPDATE  NEW and OLD references are
>   valid
> - DELETE  OLD references are valid
>
> If a WHEN clause is supplied,
> the SQL statements specified are only executed if the WHEN clause is
> true. If no WHEN clause is supplied, the SQL statements are executed
> every time the trigger fires.[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

You can ascertain what triggers exist by using :-

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'trigger';
```

You would need to either amend the TRIGGER (DROP and CREATE the TRIGGER using **old.number** instead of **new.number**), or DROP the TRIGGER.

Comment: OH, I forgot that I have triggers to FTS table. I need to change them. So stupid mistake. Sorry for wasting your time.